# Statistics- Finding Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

A local lawn service has determined the average time it takes to mow an average residential yard is thirty-five minutes. If mowing times are independent and constant, what is the probability it will take no more than forty-five minutes to mow a given yard?

It DOES NOT give the standard deviation. Am I supposed to assume a certain standard deviation because the term "independent and constant" connotes a certain probability distribution function? With the standard deviation, we could find the $z$-score and find $p$ that way. Otherwise, is there a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: Similarly: The average time a customer spends waiting in the check-out line at Wal-Mart is seven minutes. If wait times are independent and constant, what is the probability the customer will spend between eight and ten minutes waiting in the line?

Comment: Hard to know what is intended.  Quite possibly the standard deviation was left out by mistake, and you may be inttended to assume rough normality. Or maybe you are intended to use the [Markov Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Markov%27s_inequality) which will give a (usually) poor bound.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, André. I don't think that the standard dev. was left out by mistake, because there is another similar question.
[[See my first comment]]

I will look into the Markov Inequality. Thank you again.

Comment: Then Markov Inequality is the only standard tool I can think of.  I really do not understand "and constant." Perhaps *very* informal for identically distributed.

Comment: In a well-regulated society, the challenge of textbook questions would be to work out the answer, not to discern the question. But, alas....

Answer (score 0):

Four *speculative* scenarios follow: Perhaps the context of
the problem in the text or lectures could provide a clue
which (if any) might be intended.

1) **Uniform.** Perhaps, somehow, "constant" is supposed to suggest a uniform
distribution. To have mean 35, that would have to be $X \sim Unif(0, 70),$ so $P(X \le 45) = 45/70 = 0.6429.$

2) **Normal.** Some yards may take almost no time and some much
more. If a normal distribution is assumed that might imply $\sigma \approx 10$
so that zero is a little more than three SD below the mean.
Then $X \sim Norm(\mu=35, \sigma=10),$ and $P(X \le 45) \approx
.84.$ from the 'Empirical Rule' or normal tables.
[As suggested in one Comment by @AndreNicholas, but with the
Empirical Rule instead of Markov Inequality.]

3) **Exponential.** Often when $\mu$ is given and $\sigma$ is
not, then one is expected to assume an exponential distribution
(for which $\mu = \sigma).$ In that case, $P(X \le 45) = 7235.$
[As suggested in the comment by @Blaine.]

4) **Degenerate.** If 'constant' is taken to be 'degenerate' (at 35),
then it's a trick questions with $P(X \le 45) = 1.$

Computations from R:

```
 punif(45, 0, 70)
 ## 0.6428571
 pnorm(45, 35, 10)
 ## 0.8413447
 pexp(45, 1/35)
 ## 0.723547
```